# Windows 10, Screensaver greyed out

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I'm trying to change/add a screensaver to my laptop but when i open the screensaver window, everything is grayed out. Nothing is clickable, just the Ok, Cancel and Apply is clickable but don't do anything.

[image: Unclickable dropdown menu and preview]

Comment: Adding some images to your post might be helpful for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your sytem is not connected to a domain, then try this:

Start `Regedit.exe` and goto:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Delete these values in the right-pane:

- SCRNSAVE.EXE
- ScreenSaverIsSecure
- ScreenSaveTimeout

Repeat the same here, if the key/values are present:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Logoff and login back.

If you've used the Local Group Policy Editor to configure ScreenSaver Policy, you need to reverse the settings there instead of Regedit.exe

Answer (score 4):

If your PC is on a Windows domain and these settings are enforced by a domain Group Policy, then you can still BLOCK the GPO settings from being (re)applied.

Click 'Start' button, start typing 'regedit' when the tool appears, right click the regedit tool and choose to 'Run as Administrator'.

Modify the screen saver settings in this registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
to whatever settings you need.

Here is the smart bit to stop the GPO being re-applied…
Make sure you modify the PERMISSIONS on the 'Desktop' registry branch.

On the left folders view, right click on the 'Desktop' folder.

Click on Permissions > Advanced > Disable inheritance > Convert to explicit (this keeps the permissions the same).

Now set all 'Principal' items (users and groups) **except your own username** to Read only.  Set/leave your own user to full control.

Apply > OK > OK
Exit the registry
Log off/on or Reboot, job done.

Cheers,
BG-UK

Comment: This is extra info for people having a GPO forced on them and they want to reset and deny the system admin rights to change this again.